# Guidelines for what to do after someone dies

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam, death

Does Islam have any procedures which family members are supposed to do after the death of one of their family members?  For example, after the burial, I've heard that some people host Quranic recitation for the dead for 40 days non stop.

Others don't seem to do such a thing, anyone know more about this?

Please understand, I am not asking if you should recite the quran in groups for 40 days after the death of someone, I am asking if Islam has any guidelines of what should be done (if anything) after a burial.

Comment: There are no such guidelines. The best you can do is pray to Allah for the dead person and ask for his maghfirah. Reciting the Qur'an in groups and "transferring" the virtues to the dead person are all innovations, and all innovations are useless exercises at best or lead to the Hell Fire at worst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is to give him a burial. Even if you don't know the person you should follow his [funeral procession](http://authentichadithfoundation.org/sahih-bukhari-1240/).

The other thing to do ask Allah for his forgiveness. One of the only three things that can benefit a person after his death is [dua by his children](http://hadithaday.org/islamic-manners/had-357-when-a-man-dies-his-deeds-come-to-an-end-except-for-three/).

This also means that other things like hosting quran recitation, saying his missed prayers etc will not benefit him.

You can also continue doing good things that he has started or spread any knowledge which the deceased has generated e.g. publishing a book of his research.